# delete an item in a list of (events ) in a list of (dates)

Tags: python, list, events

```
def command_add(date, event, calendar):
if date not in calendar:
    calendar[date] = list()
calendar[date].append(event)


calendar = {}
command_add("2015-10-29", "Python class", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-12", "Eye doctor", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-12", "lunch with sid", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-29", "Change oil in blue car", calendar) 
command_add("2015-10-29", "test car", calendar)
print(calendar)

def command_show(calendar):
    for (date, event) in sorted(calendar.items()):
        print(date+':')
        for i in enumerate(event):
            print('    '+str(i[0])+': '+i[1])

command_show(calendar)

def command_delete(date, entry_number, calendar):
 for (date, event) in sorted(calendar.items()):
     for i in enumerate(event):
        del i[entry_number]

def command_delete(date, entry_number, calendar):
     for (date, event) in sorted(calendar.items()):
         for i in enumerate(event):
             i.remove(entry_number)


command_delete("2015-10-29", 2, calendar)
command_show(calendar)
```

i tried these 2 methods but I can't seem to figure out how to access the events to delete a specific event on a date
the call on command_delete should delete the 3rd entry of the command_add function since it starts counting from 0

the error's i get  tuple object doesnt support item deletion or remove

Comment: `enumerate` returns a `tuple`: i.e.`(0, event[0]), (1, event[1]), (2, event[2]),...` That means `i` is a `tuple`, which is immutable

Comment: there are numerous problems with the code. 0) two functions bear the name `command_delete`. 1) The `date` parameter is overwritten and therefore lost. 2) Where is the code that checks the `date` parameter matches? i.e. the `date` parameter is unused. 3) Why are you sorting the calendar? Then use `bisect` on the sorted seq... 4) the indentation in the `command_add` function is wrong

Comment: yea i put 2 option for command delete that i attempted becuase they both didnt work and i thought maybe people would atleast like to see that i tried something and what i am attemption to do. im sorting the calendar so when i print it it outputs in the correct order of  the dates. also if i is a tuple can i just delete the entire tuple

Comment: Study my answer, I fixed and simplified your code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my initial comments to your code:

numerous problems I can see; e.g.

0) two functions bear the name `command_delete`.

1) In the `command_delete` function:

1.1) The date parameter is overwritten and therefore lost.

1.2) Where is the code that checks the date parameter matches? i.e. the date parameter is unused.

1.3) Why are you sorting the calendar?

1.4) `enumerate` returns a tuple: i.e.(0, event[0]), (1, event[1](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/defaultdict.html)), (2, event[2]),... That means i is a tuple, which is immutable. Surprisingly, in the `command_show` you use it as a tuple, correctly, and not here.

2) the indentation in the `command_add` function is wrong

Now try with this

```
from collections import defaultdict

def command_add(date, event, calendar):
    calendar[date].append(event)


def command_show(calendar):
    for date, event in sorted(calendar.items()):
        print(date+':')
        for i, el in enumerate(event):
            print('    {}: {}'.format(i, el))


def command_delete(date, entry_number, calendar):
    events = calendar.get(date)
    if events:
        del events[entry_number]


calendar = defaultdict(list)

command_add("2015-10-29", "Python class", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-12", "Eye doctor", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-12", "lunch with sid", calendar)
command_add("2015-10-29", "Change oil in blue car", calendar) 
command_add("2015-10-29", "test car", calendar)
command_show(calendar)

print('now lets delete the "test car" appointment')

command_delete("2015-10-29", 2, calendar)
command_show(calendar)
```

which produces

```
2015-10-12:
    0: Eye doctor
    1: lunch with sid
2015-10-29:
    0: Python class
    1: Change oil in blue car
    2: test car
now lets delete the "test car" appointment
2015-10-12:
    0: Eye doctor
    1: lunch with sid
2015-10-29:
    0: Python class
    1: Change oil in blue car
```

Please do take the time to study the behaviour of `defaultdict`, for example on [PMOTW](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/defaultdict.html)

Comment: this is really nice code i like how u cleaned up my command show it a lot more logical. the .get method is really nice for handling the events too. just for my clarification how can u just stay if events: how is that a condition. I appreciate it

Comment: `calendar.get(date)`, by default, returns `None` if the `date` key is not present in the dictionary. And the value `None` is considered `False` when interpreted in a boolean expression. Just as the integer `0` (zero) and the empty string `""`

Comment: if you think my answer solves your problem correctly and better than others', please mark it as accepted. Thank you.